# script to compress multiple files

Tags: backup, scripts

I have a script that generates backup and finds files older than 30 days and compresses them. Now the problem I'm facing is if the files are more than one than how can I edit the script so that it compresses all those files as well. Below is the find function Im using. Please Help.

```
Time=+30
PATH_TO_DUMP=/home/tarun/Desktop/Backup

#Find any Backup File defined by the time constraint
file="$(find $PATH_TO_DUMP -type f -mtime $Time)"

#To verify if $file is empty or has some value
if [ ! -n "$file" ]; then
echo "No Earlier Backups were found to compress" >> $PATH_TO_LOG
else
echo "Earlier Backups $file will be compressed" >> $PATH_TO_LOG
gzip $file
fi
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you will have to use a loop. Look into 'for' loops.

Comment: @matv1 : I tried to apply it but didnt worked Im not so in scripting can u please specify a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full script? I think it will be usefull to all of us :) Ty in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a minor modification

(pipe the **find** output into **while** loop doing a  **read**)

```sh
Time=+30
PATH_TO_DUMP=/home/tarun/Desktop/Backup
#Find any Backup File defined by the time constraint

find $PATH_TO_DUMP -type f -mtime $Time | while read file
do

  #To verify if $file is empty or has some value
  if [ ! -n "$file" ]; then
    echo "No Earlier Backups were found to compress" >> $PATH_TO_LOG
  else
    echo "Earlier Backups $file will be compressed" >> $PATH_TO_LOG
    gzip "$file"
  fi

done
```

Comment: xargs solution is also a "one liner" option `find $PATH_TO_DUMP -type f -mtime $Time | xargs -tn1 gzip` (`-tn1` because you seems to like verbose scripts :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks Emmanuel. I found your script is working perfectly but after it has compressed files in .gz format in other turn it logs those files again for compression(It doesnt does that). I want to know how can I change the find parameter to exclude .gz file.

Comment: @Tarun ok then try `find $PATH_TO_DUMP -type f -mtime $Time ! -name \*gz | xargs -tn1 gzip`  or that one to avoid any compressed files `find $PATH_TO_DUMP -type f -mtime $Time | egrep -v "\.(zip|gz|tgz|rar)$"  | xargs -tn1 gzip`

Answer (score 2):

Compress all the file with `tar` instead of `gzip`:

```
tar jcvf new_file.tar.bz2 $file
```

tar stores file
`-j` to `bzip` the tarred file (`-z` use `gzip`)
`-c` to create (`-x` to extract )
`-v` verbose
`-f` file to create ( or to open )

To extract:

```
tar jxvf new_file.tar.bz2
```

Otherwise, if you want an archive for every file:

```
echo $file | xargs gzip
```

xargs reads items from  the  standard  input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected
       with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and  executes
       the  command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any initial-
       arguments followed by items read from standard input.

Comment: I dont think tar will be useful because it will create a new zipped file I used gzip because it zips the original file so not makes any new compressed copies of it.

Comment: @Tarun Then delete the uncompressed files (and exclude the tar.bz2 from a new archive:     --exclude=$PATH_TO_DUMP/*.tar.bz2)

Comment: Ok thats fine but will it be able to compress multiple files as multiple files like file1 to file1.tar.bz2 and file2 to file2.tar.bz2 in that situation.

Comment: I thought you want only one archive. However, I've modify my answer